# Site close v/s Delete in SharePoint

Tags: site-deletion, close

Can some one please explain me difference b/w closing and deleting a site in SharePoint 2013. You can see the option in site policy under 'site collection Administration' in Site setting. Screenshot is attahced below.

[image]

Comment: You can read it on the left of the image you shared, starting with "When a site is closed, ........"

Comment: Yes its pretty much described on the left hand side

Comment: @Arsalan Adam Khatri May be description is easy enough. But I am not able to understand the first line of description. Could you please elaborate in little more details. .

Answer (score 1):

It is related to policies, closing a site indicates that the site is no longer in use and can eventually be deleted according to a schedule. A closed site does not appear in places like Delve, but users can still modify the closed site and its content by using the URL to reach the site.

you could create a policy that deletes a site three months after the site is closed, or a policy that deletes a site one year after the site is created.

Hope this helps ;)

Additional info:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-policies-for-site-closure-and-deletion-a8280d82-27fd-48c5-9adf-8a5431208ba5

Comment: It means after closing site I can access URL, fill form (if any ) and can save into sharepoint list and also workflow will work (if any). Also is closing a site a indication to user that site is soon gonna be deleted?